# Is this possible to write a program to inter-act with existing software?

Tags: python, automation

For example, if the program did not provide an API, and I need it to do something from Python script, is this possible to do so? Let's give an example:

I would like to copy the `Product ID` from the `Internet Explorer`'s product ID everyday and new a text file named in this format: `ddmmyyyy`, and store on desktop. It is stupid, so, I would like to handle it to the machine to do it. (Yes, it is useless, but just say, it is an example.)

Creating a text file, with a string is easy to implement, but the REAL question is, how can I get the product ID from the program that don't have API provided.

So, the IE didn't provide the API for developer to access the `Product ID`, and I think the value can be shown on the screen or registry. Assume that I don't know the register location or they simply didn't store it in the registry, what I can get this  product ID is manually, click, and check. For this process, is this possible to make it automatic? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If the Info ur looking for is showed by IE you can obtain it by using xpath. If you want to make it automatic you could use selenium which works with webs as well.

If the program doesnt provide an api then its not possible to interact with the program unless you get the output from a browser or you may use programs like Sikuli and obtain the info for example by image processing

Comment: It is not a web content shown on IE, but the content in the application. You can change the IE to Office, or iTunes, just something that don't provide API for u to query/get their information.

Comment: Try Sikuli,you can click anywhere and if its text you can take a picture of it and take the text out of it.  I believe Sikuli is capable of all of those!